# Design Issue with firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mozilla

I have my site [Khanawal.com](http://khanawal.com) ,In page [home page](http://khanawal.com/Home.aspx) center there is search box which really looks good on chrome and IE 10.

but Mozilla is giving me design issue for the same, Elements are loosing there positions, search box is getting distorted , I'm using twitter bootstrap for CSS. What i'm missing , or where i'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `float: right;` to these add ons and i think you should be good

```
<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-map-marker"></i></span>

<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
```

Comment: That worked like a charm..now the search button looks little different, any thoughts on the same?

Comment: huhh not sure.. i dont see any difference

Answer (score 1):

since the parent is floating left try floating the span right

```
span.add-on {
float:right;
}
```